# Remove box character after excerpts. Special Character Bug

Tags: excerpt

I want to hide these special charecter (������) after excerpts ..

e.g.

"Los votos del PP han impedido este jueves que el Parlament apruebe instar al Govern a que en un plazo de mes establezca un calendario en el que detalle las fechas en las que hará efectivos los pagos a los proveedores. Los 'populares **�����**"

"“सीएमएस मीडिया लेब” द्वारा जारी आकडे बताते हैं की इन चैनलो ने अपने प्राइम टाइम  के कुल समय का
**������**"

plz guide me

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the [`excerpt_more`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more) filter to modify this text. e.g.:

```
function mytheme_filter_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return $more = '[read more]';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'mytheme_filter_excerpt_more' );
```

You'll also want to make sure that nothing else is *applying* this filter, as it may be the cause of your problem. (If not that, then there is probably an issue with the character encoding, or internationalization/translation strings, etc. for your Theme.)